# Resource not found when trying to delete from Cosmos DB

Tags: c#, .net, azure-cosmosdb

When I try to delete a resource for Cosmos DB I get following error: Resource not found. It begins to happen when I started using a unlimited collection with a partion key. This worked fine without partionkey and a limit 10gb collection.

```
protected async Task<bool> DeleteDocument(Resource document)
    {
        var documentUri = UriFactory.CreateDocumentUri(_db.Options.Value.DatabaseName, _db.Options.Value.CollectionName, document.Id);

        ResourceResponse<Document> result = null;

        var options = new RequestOptions
        {
            PartitionKey = new PartitionKey("moachingpartionkey")
        };

        for (int i = 0; i < MaxRetryCount; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                result = await _db.Client.DeleteDocumentAsync(documentUri, options);
                break;
            }
            catch (DocumentClientException dex) when (dex.StatusCode.HasValue && (int)dex.StatusCode.Value == 429)
            {
                _logger.LogWarning($"");
                await Task.Delay(dex.RetryAfter);
            }
        }

        if (result == null)
            return false;

        int statusCode = (int)result.StatusCode;
        return statusCode >= 200 && statusCode < 300;
    }
```

Here is my create:

```
protected async Task<bool> CreateDocumentAsync(Resource document)
    {
        var collectionUri = UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(_db.Options.Value.DatabaseName, _db.Options.Value.CollectionName);

        ResourceResponse<Document> result = null;

        for (int i = 0; i < MaxRetryCount; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                result = await _db.Client.CreateDocumentAsync(collectionUri, document);
                break;
            }
            catch (DocumentClientException dex) when (dex.StatusCode.HasValue && (int)dex.StatusCode.Value == 429)
            {
                _logger.LogWarning($"");
                await Task.Delay(dex.RetryAfter);
            }
        }

        if (result == null)
            return false;

        int statusCode = (int)result.StatusCode;
        return statusCode >= 200 && statusCode < 300;
    }
```

Comment: It's unclear from your code but the `PartitionKey` object represents the value of the partition key not the definition.

Comment: Do you need to specify the `PartitionKey` when creating the Document URI?

Comment: @AndrewTFinnell No I do not.

Comment: It is probably because the document does not exist in the partition that you have specified, which is also why the delete works when you don't specify the partition key.

Comment: @bit How do I specify the partition key on create?

Comment: You could do this while creating the collection `collection.PartitionKey.Paths.Add("/YourPartitionKeyPath");`

Comment: Also, Can you Ascertain that the document exists first? Because I used to get exception if it did not actually exist. I am adding the code i use as an answer below, have a look

Answer (score 1):

Since you have asked in the comments, here is the code I use to add partition key while creating the collection:

```
var collection = new DocumentCollection
{
    Id = "Customers", // just an example collection
};

// Set partition key
collection.PartitionKey.Paths.Add("/CountryId"); // just an example of the partition key path

// Set throughput
var options = new RequestOptions
{
    OfferThroughput = 400, // Default value is 10000. Currently set to minimum value to keep costs low.
};

// Create
await client.CreateDocumentCollectionIfNotExistsAsync(
   UriFactory.CreateDatabaseUri("YourCosomosDatabaseId"),
   collection,
   options);
```

Here is the code I use to Delete a document. Note that I check if it exists first, otherwise I get exception.

```
 // Check if it exists, otherwise delete throws
 var doc = await GetByIdAsync(id, 99); // your method to fetch the document by Id, the partition key (CountryId) is 99 
 if (doc == null)
 {
     return true; // Indicates successful deletion
 }

 // Delete
 var uri = UriFactory.CreateDocumentUri("YourCosomosDatabaseId", "Customers", id);
 var reqOptions = new RequestOptions { PartitionKey = new PartitionKey(99) }; // CountryId is 99
 var result = await Client.DeleteDocumentAsync(uri, reqOptions);
 return result.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NoContent;
```

> To clarify a bit of the terminology-
>   When you say `PartitionKey` you
>   imply a value like an `int` or `string` e.g `99` above.
>
> Whereas when you say `PartitionkeyPath` you imply the property
>   path/name in the document e.g `/CountryId` in above.

References for [IDocumentClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.documents.idocumentclient.createdatabaseifnotexistsasync?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_Documents_IDocumentClient_CreateDatabaseIfNotExistsAsync_Microsoft_Azure_Documents_Database_Microsoft_Azure_Documents_Client_RequestOptions_) and [DocumentClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.documents.client.documentclient.createdocumentcollectionifnotexistsasync?view=azure-dotnet)

Comment: Thank for the answer. But I can't find any method name CreateDocumentCollectionIfNotExistsAsync inside IDocumentClient Client

Comment: FYI - when I created my unlimited collection i gave it following partitionkey = moachingpartionkey

Comment: Your are probably on a different version of the nuget package see this : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.documents.idocumentclient.createdatabaseifnotexistsasync?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_Documents_IDocumentClient_CreateDatabaseIfNotExistsAsync_Microsoft_Azure_Documents_Database_Microsoft_Azure_Documents_Client_RequestOptions_ or this :https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/simple-crud-operations-in-cosmos-db/